# User Profiles email property not getting updated in SharePoint

Tags: user-profile-service, ad

We have SharePoint 2013 on-premise site, where users from "ABC" AD domain are accessing the site. Now some of the users got new account and email on "XYZ" domain, but still they are part of "ABC" domain to access our site but email has been terminated.

Now our AD administrator changed there email from name@abc.com to name@xyz.com in our AD "ABC". But this email is not getting updated in SharePoint User profile and still it shows old email id. And hence no mail goes to them.

This issue is occuring for existing users only. If any new users get added and they put email id as name@xyz.com it is comhing in sharepoint.

Comment: Did you try a full synch?

Comment: Yes i have ran the timer job for user profile full sync and incremental sync but it is not reflecting.

Comment: Try to change an other property in  your AD and then sych, just to check if is only that field that not get update. Check also the file log, maybe something is going wrong

Comment: Which file log i need to check? Also we have other SP 2013 server, when i checked there the user profile was showing new email id. The difference is the user don't have access to any site on that server, just for testing i added and checked the email property and it was there with new email.

Comment: The ULS log. So you solved adding the user to one site in the farm?

Comment: Issue is not solved yet, these are two different farms. On one farm i can see the changes are reflected, but on other those are not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23010/discussion-between-p-s-and-nk-sp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the site collection users list, which is where this info is stored.  There are two timer jobs that control this:

"User Profile Service Application Name" - User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization

"User Profile Service Application Name" - User Profile to SharePoint Quick Synchronization

Where "User Profile Service Application Name" is the name of the user profile service application.  The full runs hourly, the quick every 5 minutes.  They require information about the user to be correct in the user profile store.  I would be that is where your issue lies.  The reason it works for new users added is because people picker is resolving the user info real-time from AD and not the user profile service application.  Then once you select them and they login to the site, they are added to site collection users.  Once they are added to the site collections users, that info is used instead.  You can view the site collection users by looking a group id 0 on the site collection (easiest way to do this is open a group, then change the ID to 0 in the URL, and press enter of course).

A fix outside of user profile service application is deleting the users from the site collection users list and adding them again (slow, tedious and you need to make sure you add them to the right group(s) again).

Comment: So i should delete user from site collection and re add them? Also should i need to delete from CA also? By the way is CA also it shows old email id.

Comment: Hi, after deleting user from site collection and re adding them worked. I done this for one test user and it worked. But is it recommended? Can i update there email using code in user profile. These are around 100 users for whom email is changed

Comment: Sorry, just saw this.  No harm in doing it, it's just tedious.

Answer (score 1):

Profiles are first imported via User Profile Synchronization which is part of the User Profile Service Application. Then, a scheduled timer job is supposed to sync the latest updated profile data to each site collection.

Each site collection stores a copy of the user profile information in it's User list. I believe if a user logs in and the user's profile information is not in the user list, it is added to the list with data pulled from the Service App profile database or AD.

You can manually run the "stsadm -o sync" command to tell SharePoint to run the synchronization script that synchronizes the site collection user list data with the user profile data from the shared services provider.

Note: If you continue to have issues, it is possible to delete the individual user's profile information for the particular site. However, not recommended.